# git (interactive) rebase fixup does not adhere to commit.cleanup = scissors setting?

Tags: git

So our commit logs always start with `#workitemid: rest of title`. This poses an issue when writing a commit message. Therefor we have the `commit.cleanup` setting set to `scissors`.

However, it seems like `git rebase -i <hash>` using `fixup`  ignores this setting and errors out with "aborting due to empty commit message"

Is there a known workaround for this behaviour? We are currently on git version `2.17.1.windows.2` I am unaware whether this could be fixed in a newer version of git for windows.

Answer (score 0):

The release notes of version 2.22.0 have this to say:

> The list of conflicted paths shown in the editor while concluding a conflicted merge was shown above the scissors line when the clean-up mode is set to "scissors", even though it was commented out just like the list of updated paths and other information to help the user explain the merge better.

While this does not address your case directly, [the change that fixed this item](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1a2b985fb375e7ce14932bfc59365024af2fb6ab#diff-79231f0693f84f3951daeea17065aad9) looks like it could also have solved your problem.

You should upgrade to version 2.22.0 at least.

Comment: Well, sadly, it doesn't work. Even worse, it just completely silently removes the whole commit message.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem with git 2.25.1 and started to submit a bug report.

For verification I also tried git 2.35.1 (the newest release) and found this bug seems to have been fixed.
I haven't checked the release notes of the in-between version to find out when exactly this change was added.